# Problems exporting entries from ExpressionEngine 3 with Feed Me 2 beta plugin

Tags: plugin-feedme

I am trying to export entries from my EE 3 install to Craft and import them using the Feed Me 2 beta plugin.

I believe I have followed the instructions on creating a template from within ExpressionEngine 3 with the export.php code from engram-design's github.  I have enabled PHP on the template from within EE.

When I run the `mysite-url/export?id=1` file, it gives me this error page:

> {!-- ra:0000000004427cd500000000745c77df --}
>   Notice
>
> Undefined property: EE_Functions::$EE
>
> ee/legacy/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code, line 4 show details
>
> Severity: E_NOTICE
>   Notice
>
> Trying to get property of non-object
>
> ee/legacy/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code, line 4 show details
>
> Severity: E_NOTICE
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home/iwatermt/public_html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code:4 Stack trace: #0 /home/iwatermt/public_html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Functions.php(680): eval() #1 /home/iwatermt/public_html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Template.php(1825): EE_Functions->evaluate('{!-- ra:0000000...') #2 /home/iwatermt/public_html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Template.php(559): EE_Template->parse_template_php('{!-- ra:0000000...') #3 /home/iwatermt/public_html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Template.php(237): EE_Template->parse('{!-- ra:0000000...', false, '1', false) #4 /home/iwatermt/public_html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Template.php(168): EE_Template->fetch_and_parse('', Array, false) #5 /home/iwatermt/public_html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Core.php(680): EE_Template->run_template_engine('', '') #6 /home/iwatermt/public_html/system/ee/legacy/controllers/ee.php(68): EE_Core->generate_page() #7 [internal function]: EE->index() #8 /home/iwatermt/p in /home/iwatermt/public_html/system/ee/legacy/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code on line 4

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For those of us not that familiar with the plugin, can you link to the instructions you followed? I assume it will reference some template code you wrote that would probably be helpful to share as well.

Comment: I attempted to use the ExpressionEngine plugin by engram-design named export.php.  But the developer told me that this plugin only worked for ExpressionEngine 2 and I'm on EE 3.  So, I'm looking for other options to export my entries out of EE 3 into Craft.

Answer (score 1):

Just some additional context here, we're referring to the guide for Feed Me 2 [here](http://sgroup.com.au/plugins/feedme/guides/migrating-from-ee-to-craft), which leads to the Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/engram-design/5fbe54ef0abb15e3ff6f667291098464). This Gist has not been tested with EE3, but should work just fine for EE2.

That Gist is really just a guide to get you started quickly with an export. It's in no way a requirement, as you can simply create your own JSON or XML templates in Expression Engine to output your content. Once that's done, its over to Feed Me to continue as normal.

You might like to refer to https://github.com/rsanchez/json or simply write your own JSON/XML templates.